# Pulseaudio module-loopback problems

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluez

I'm trying to setup bluetooth audio sink using bluez + pulseaudio. The computer is running debian 7. I'm able to connect another device via bluetooth and I can see it in input devices.
I've found information, that to play sound from input device I need to load loopback pulseaudio module and I did so:
`pactl load-module module-loopback source="bluez_source.2C_FF_EE_2D_22_51" sink="alsa_output.platform-sunxi-codec.analog-stereo"`
Such command creates two loopbacks, one in playback and one in recording. The recording loopback device seems to be the one, that is getting the audio from bluetooth input while there is no activity on the loopback in playback tab and there is no sound audible from the speakers.
Did I use the wrong module? Did I choose wrong sink/source? I've chosen from `pactl list sinks/sources short`. I've tried loading loopback without specifying the source or sink but it didn't work either.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You say you want a bluetooth audio sink (= loadspeaker), but you connect up a BT source (= microphone) to a PC speaker. Also, I've never seen "loopbacks" in the playback/record tab of pavucontrol, what you see are the actual sources/sinks and the activity on them. So, do you want to output sound on your BT device (loadspeaker), or do you want to input sound from it (microphone)?

Comment: I have 3 things: "phone", server and speakers. Speakers are connected to server with jack. The phone is supposed to connect via bluetooth and the server should play music from phone via speakers.

Comment: Please connect all 3 things, do `pacmd list-sinks | grep name:` and `pacmd list-sources | grep name:`, and post the output, so we can see which is which.